# What does this perl regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

I've started learning regex but this has so many elements in it. What does it match?

```
$x =~s/\.?0+$//;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It matches zero or one literal dot, followed by one or more zeros, then the end of string.

```
\.     #A literal dot
?      #Zero or one of the previous character
0+     #One or more zeros
$      #End of string
```

Comment: Isn't "?" Zero or ONE of the previous characters? I might be wrong, though, but it's what I remember from regexes.

Answer (score 12):

It removes the period and trailing zeroes from the end of a string, changing '24.00' into '24'.  In pieces:

```
s/  substitute operation
\.  literal period, not a placeholder
?   Period is optional (by the way, probably a bug)
0+  one or more zeros
$   all of this at the end of the string.
//  replace it with nothing, i.e.,  just delete it.
```

The bug?  Well, '2400' would be changed to '24'.  Probably not the desired behavior.

Comment: Well spotted!  If the purpose of the regex is to remove the fractional part of a number when it contains only zeroes, the `\.` should not be treated as optional.

Answer (score 3):

There's an [App for that](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5C.?0%2b%24)!

Comment: There is a Perl module for that ! http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/YAPE::Regex::Explain